# Is there way to play audio from X11 in C++?

Tags: x11

## Plot:

I found that Xlib has an `XBell` function that should produce a notification sound.

## My Goal:

I would like to play sampled audio using X11 in C++, maybe it's not intended for but so, is there any way to play sampled audio with X11?

### Required features:

- Be able to play sampled sound
- Using X11

## Problems:

I hardly found anything else than the `XBell` instruction in Xlib for X11.

I may be totally wrong and X11 isn't intended to play audio.

If any clarification is needed, please add a comment or suggest an edit

Comment: X11 is a protocol that's independent of the platform and programming language. I removed the "linux" and "c++" tags for that reason. Anyhow, the X11 protocol can be found online, including its many extensions. I don't believe an extension for audio exists though. That said, why does it have to be X11? If it doesn't have to, you can find lots of programs that use X11 and play sound, which you can use as examples.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt The C++ tag is because I intended to do it especially in C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## X11 isn't intended to play audio.

Instead, you can either use ALSA, PulseAudio or OSS.

#### ALSA

Is a low level infrastructure for Audio in Linux but it's risky and not easy to use.

#### OSS

Is obsolete but better than X11 to play audio!

#### PulseAudio

Is a high level infrastructure for Audio in Linux but it's more flexible.
It's the way to go if you want to target modern distributions.